# Stretch out empty DIV 100% and get height of it

Tags: html, css

I have some html template, it has two DIVs floating left and right. One of them is higher (I don't know which, because it is just template). So there is some free space below one of these DIVs. I added empty DIVs there (free-div-1 and free-div-2) and I want they to stretching out by free height.

Why do I need this? I want to know size of free space to fill it with some content using ajax. But I always get zero-height of these blocks.

Of course, I can calculate this space as differense between the left and right DIVs. But my question is about auto-stretching out empty divs, is that possible?

Thanks.

CSS:

```
.first {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  background:aqua;
}
.second {
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
  background:yellow;
}
.container {
  width: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
}
/* Without text trick the container will be of 0px height */
.container:after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden; 
}
.free-block-1, .free-block.2 {    
  background: red;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    <div class="first-content">
      <p>First content block. Can have any height.</p>
      <p>First content block. Can have any height.</p>
      <p>First content block. Can have any height.</p>
      <p>First content block. Can have any height.</p>
      <p>First content block. Can have any height.</p>
      <p>First content block. Can have any height.</p>
      <p>First content block. Can have any height.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="free-block-1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <div class="first-content">
      <p>Second content block. Can have any height.</p>
      <p>Second content block. Can have any height.</p>
      <p>Second content block. Can have any height.</p>
      <p>Second content block. Can have any height.</p>      
    </div>
    <div class="free-block-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Real example: http://jsbin.com/edubar/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

Literally just answered this question here: [Vertically align to a dynamic height from another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898200/vertically-align-to-a-dynamic-height-from-another-div/9898268#9898268)

Basically, use the table model instead of CSS's box model. Then it will act like a table, and cells stretch to the entire height of the table.

Here's the updated bin: http://jsbin.com/edubar/5/edit

Comment: I don't want to set height 100% of this DIV, I want to set height 100% of DIV below (free-block-1 and free-block-2).

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just change your css file as like

```
  .first {
  width: 200px;
  background:aqua;
    display:table-cell;
}
.second {
  background:yellow;
    display:table-cell;
}
.container {
  width: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
}
/* Without text trick the container will be of 0px height */
.container:after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.free-block-1, .free-block-2 {    
  background: red;

}
```

[now link is here please check to it](http://jsfiddle.net/H3Z9z/)

http://jsfiddle.net/H3Z9z/